# Does NumPy array really take less memory than python list?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

Please refer to below execution -

```
import sys

_list = [2,55,87]
print(f'1 - Memory used by Python List - {sys.getsizeof(_list)}')
      
narray = np.array([2,55,87])
size = narray.size * narray.itemsize
print(f'2 - Memory usage of np array using itemsize  - {size}')
print(f'3 - Memory usage of np array using getsizeof  - {sys.getsizeof(narray)}')
```

Here is what I get in result

```
1 - Memory used by Python List - 80
2 - Memory usage of np array using itemsize  - 12
3 - Memory usage of np array using getsizeof  - 116
```

One way of calculation suggests numpy array is consuming way too less memory but other says it is consuming more than regular python list? Shouldn't I be using getSizeOf with numpy array. What I am doing wrong here?

Edit - I just checked, an empty python list is consuming 56 bytes whereas an empty np array 104. Is this space being used in pointing to associated built-in methods and attributes?

Comment: getsize is nearly useless with lists.  And test the size of a large array (1000 items] before you worry about what getsize shows you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation using:

```
size = narray.size * narray.itemsize
```

does not include the memory consumed by non-element attributes of the array object. This can be verified by the documentation of [`ndarray.nbytes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html):

```
>>> x = np.zeros((3,5,2), dtype=np.complex128)
>>> x.nbytes
480
>>> np.prod(x.shape) * x.itemsize
480
```

In the above link, it can be read that `ndarray.nbytes`:

> Does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the
> array object.

Note that from the code above you can conclude that your calculation excludes non-element attributes given that the value is equal to the one from `ndarray.nbytes`.

A list of the non-element attributes can be found in the section [Array Attributes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#array-attributes), including here for completeness:

> **ndarray.flags** Information about the memory layout of the array.
> **ndarray.shape** Tuple of array dimensions.
> **ndarray.strides** Tuple of
> bytes to step in each dimension when traversing an array.
> **ndarray.ndim** Number of array dimensions.
> **ndarray.data** Python buffer object pointing  to the start of the array’s data.
> **ndarray.size** Number of elements in the array.
> **ndarray.itemsize** Length of one array element in bytes.
> **ndarray.nbytes** Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array.
> **ndarray.base** Base object if memory is from some other object.

With regards to [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) it can be read in the documentation (emphasis mine) that:

> Only the memory consumption **directly attributed to the object** is
> accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

Answer (score 4):

Search on `[numpy]getsizeof` produces many potential duplicates.

The basic points are:

1. a list is a container, and `getsizeof` docs warns us that it returns only the size of the container, not the size of the elements that it references.  So by itself it is an unreliable measure to the total size of a list (or tuple or dict).
2. `getsizeof` is a fairly good measure of arrays, if you take into account the roughly 100 bytes of "overhead".  That overhead will be a big part of a small array, and a minor thing when looking at a large one.  `nbytes` is the simpler way of judging array memory use.
3. But for `views`, the data-buffer is shared with the base, and doesn't count when using `getsizeof`.
4. object dtype arrays contain references like lists, to the same `getsizeof` caution applies.

Overall I think  understanding how arrays and lists are stored is more useful way of judging their respective memory use. Focus more on the computational efficiency than memory use.  For small stuff, and iterative uses, lists are better.  Arrays are best when they are large, and you use array methods to do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Because `numpy` arrays have shapes, strides, and other member variables that define the data layout it is reasonable that (might) require some extra memory for this!

A `list` on the other hand has no specific type, or shape, etc.

Although, if you start appending elements on a list instead of simply writing them as an array, and also go to larger numbers of elements, e.g. 1e7, you will see different behaviour!

Example case:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

N = int(1e7)

narray = np.zeros(N);
mylist = []

for i in range(N):
    mylist.append(narray[i])

print("size of np.array:", sys.getsizeof(narray))
print("size of list    :", sys.getsizeof(mylist))
```

On my (ASUS) Ubuntu 20.04 PC I get:

```
size of np.array: 80000104
size of list    : 81528048
```

**Note** that is not only the memory footprint important in an application's efficiency! The data layout is sometimes way more important.

Comment: This answer, like the question, still do not factor the size of the elements IN the list. sys.getsizeof won't iterate recursively on those. The list wi be one or two order of magnitudes larger, as all elements are full Python int objects, and that should be the point here